# Equation wider than tcolorbox in twocolumn

Tags: equations, boxes, tcolorbox, fit

I have a large equation I would like to fit within `tcolorbox` in a `\twocolumn` page without split it. Could you please help me to fix this?

i tired even \begin{minipage}[c]{5in} but with no luck

MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, 
                                                                                                            xshift=-2mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}

\usepackage{pifont}


\begin{document}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show that 
${\displaystyle D_2f(x,y) = \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}} \left ( \int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds \right)}$
\item prove that 
${ \displaystyle \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}  \right)\left(\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \right) x\neq y\, \text{and} \, x+y \neq 2 \implies x^{2}-2x \neq y^2-2y }$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}


\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}


\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}


\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
\end{myLemma}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One `amsmath` will do… What are the $15$ empty lemmas for?

Comment: Just example to make towcolum, how can i fix that with amsmath thank u

Comment: What about using `align` to split your equations?

Comment: i don't want to split it

Comment: if you don't want to split it, make it smaller, with `\small`  but also most of those `\left`/`\right` should be removed (they are just taking up horizontal space you don't have)

Comment: Your edit puts `\small` inside the math mode which just generates errors.  You still have the unwanted extra braces and `\left`/`\right`

Comment: yes i tired even the \begin{minipage} with no luck thank you for trying to help me

Comment: why would minipage help? If you insist on setting the equation on a single line then all you can do is set it in an unreadably small font, it is simply too much text to fit on a line.

Comment: so to be readably i should split it ?

Comment: Why do you ask, it isn't a technical or tex markup question, just _look_ at the equation you are trying to fit into the stated width. unless it is a legal get-out clause that you are hoping that no one ever reads you should not even consider setting text to that font size.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the external pairs of braces. What are they here for? If you really need them, make several groups. Reduce the distance form the frame to the ledt margin of the text inside, and align the enumeration on the left margin with the `enumitem` package. Finally, if you reduce the font size, do it *outside* math mode:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \tcbset{
        lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt,
                           fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,
                           colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,
                           top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                           boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                           attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, xshift=-2mm}%
                          }, left=0mm
    }

    \newtcbtheorem{myLemma}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}

    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item Show that\\\small
${\tiny \displaystyle D_2f(x,y) = \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}} \biggl( \int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds \biggr)}$
\item Prove that\\\small
$\displaystyle \left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R} \right)\left(\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \right) x\neq y\; \text{and} \; x+y \neq 2 \implies x^{2}-2x \neq y^2-2y $
\end{enumerate}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}


    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}


    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}


    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \begin{myLemma}{}{}
    \end{myLemma}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the equation that i provide is just an example i have lots of equation that need pairs of braces. and they are too long that i have to write it in tcolorbox

Comment: I don't understand: the braces are here to make a group. The pair of `$ $` already make a group.

Comment: please check my update

Comment: @Educ: please take a look at my updated answer. I still don't understand why you need these braces.

Comment: @Bernard after edits I deleted mine so +1, but Educ, the question just seems strange it is clear that you should split these equations over two lines,  setting them small enough to fit on one line makes them unreadable.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I agree with you for the font size. Even using the medium size commands from `nccmath` can't make them fit  on one line.